# What is the purpose of bridging Kotlin and React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

So, as ýou may assume I want to build an android app. I was contemplating whether to use Kotlin or React Native code, then I saw you can make a bridge with Kotlin and RN. What is the purpose of doing that if simply making a Kotlin/RN app easier to set up?

Comment: Read [this](https://link.medium.com/UJRtBnem6mb) article, it may help you answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will possibly get a few reasons. But a summary of it is the fact that React Native may not have all the functionality you may require to build a certain type of app.

For example, you may want an app that scans the network for a specific SSID or maybe create your own network configuration profile - within React Native, that may be impossible as of now.

But by building a bridge with native code, you can create this functionality natively, and by having a bridge - you can invoke those functions via React Native.

> There may be some features that are not implemented yet in React
> Native or some device-specific features that are not supported by this
> development platform. So we can use native modules to fill the gap.
>
> Why do we need native modules in React Native apps?
>
> Who can really say! Maybe you want to make platform-specific code or
> want to reuse some existing code. For whatever the reason, React
> Native allows you to create your own native modules and expose them to
> JavaScript. The whole process is described in depth in the Native
> Modules Android documentation.

Ref: https://proandroiddev.com/react-native-bridge-with-kotlin-b2afde2f70b

Comment: what about performance? is it the same RN performance or wwill it give similar performance to native kotlin?

Comment: Well when you build a project with RN, you're basically using Gradle/Kotlin - same as you would if doing it 100% natively. I used this type of approach multiple times and no performance impact that I noticed. However, if you are referring to actual execution of code, and if the bridging slows it down - again, none that I noticed but it is possible for large apps.  There can be 'traffic jams' on the bridge itself but you have to really be sending quite a lot data back and forth to notice any impact. I have created apps on a really large scale using native network functionality and works great.

Comment: The invocation of native methods in RN is all asynchronous - so if it is take a few seconds, you'll probably just see a white screen.  Something you can handle by adding a loading spinner or similar.

Comment: i was asking, is the performance similar to RN or native kotlin?

Comment: Depends on what the app is doing at the time. If you invoke a local RN function, it will perform as RN usually does.  If you invoke a native function, it is based on how fast Kotlin can execute and how fast the response is sent back to RN via the bridge and how much data is sent back i.e. could cause a traffic jam on the bridge is large dataset is sent back, as mentioned above.